# In case of ignorance Or athiesm if one criticize ved will he incur great sin and go to hell?

Tags: vedas, sin, vivekananda, hell

I want to know if one is childish and disrespect ved without knowing much about it in ignorance. Will he face serious consequence.

Also if one with context say a material thing is greater than ved what happens to him(like replace gita with ved in famous quote of vivekanand)

Manu 2.11 :नास्तिको वेदनिन्दकः

Manu 12.94 :वेदश्चक्षुः सनातनम् ।
अशक्यं चाप्रमेयं च वेदशास्त्रमिति स्थितिः

Manu [11.56](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201933.html)
Neglecting the Veda, reviling the Veda, bearing false witness, slaying a friend, and eating of forbidden and unfit food,—these six are equal to ‘wine-drinking.’—(56)

From  [Mahabharat](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03311.htm)

He also must go to everlasting hell, who imputes falsehood to the Vedas, the scriptures, the Brahmanas, the gods, and the ceremonies in honour of the Pitris

Two related questions

1. Is there any Expatiation/atonement for those who have criticised Or abused vedas/Gods
2. Is it written anywhere not to criticize scripture like gita such as above verses for holy vedas?

Comment: Vedanindā is a serious pāpa, without doubt. You don't need to doubt Manuvacana on it, for whatever is said by Manu, is prāmāṇya. As for *everlasting hell* in Mahābhārata, I have already shared an answer on that here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58220/24460

Comment: Vedanindā actually has alternative prāyaścittas, apart from what is the prāyaścitta for surāpāna. Manu says Vedanindā is equivalent pāpakarman to surāpāna, but Yājñavalkya says Vedanindā is equivalent pāpakarman to brahmahatyā.

Comment: @Bingming well what's prayachittya

Comment: @Hope speaking falsehood of Vedas or what they say isn't criticism although in general it's bad to misrepresent or lie about content in a source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by Swami Vivekananda could be taken out of context, so I will not comment on that topic here.

But to address the general question - It is preferable to not criticize vedas or scriptures, but criticism of scriptures, by itself, is not sufficient to take one to hell or naraka. Nor is atheism, by itself, sufficient to lead one to hell.

Bhagavad Gita describes those kind of atheists that go to naraka/hell. Apart from doing veda ninda, one must also satisfy the following criteria, to be eligible for naraka -

> 16.7 Neither do the demoniacal persons under-stand what is to be done and what is not to be done; **nor does purity, or even good conduct or truthfulness exist in them.**

> 16.8 They say that the world is unreal, it has no basis, it is without a God. It is born of mutual union brought about by passion! What other (cause can there be)?

> 16.9 Holding on to this view, (these people) **who are of depraved character**, of poor intellect, **given to fearful actions and harmful**, wax strong for the ruin of the world.

> 16.10 Giving themselves up to **insatiable passion, filled with vanity, pride and arrogance, adopting bad abjectives due to delusion, and having impure resolves,** they engage in actions.

> 16.11 Beset with innumerable cares which end (only) with death, **holding that the enjoyment of desirable objects is the highest goal**, feeling sure that this is all.

> 16.12 Bound by hundreds of shackles in the form of hope, **giving themselves wholly to passion and anger, they endeavour to amass wealth through foul means for the enjoyment of desirable objects.**

> 16.13 'This has been gained by me today; I shall acire this desired object. This is in hand; again, this wealth also will come to me.'

> 16.14 'That enemy has been killed by me, and I shall kill others as well. I am the lord, I am the enjoyer, I am well-established, mighty and happy.'

> 16.15 '**I am rich and high-born; who else is there similar to me?** I shall perform sacrifices; I shall give, I shall rejoice,'-thus they are diversely deluded by non-discrimination.

> 16.16 Bewildered by numerous thoughts, caught in the net of delusion, (and) **engrossed in the enjoyment of desirable objects**, they fall into a foul hell.

> 16.17 **Self-conceited, haughty, filled with pride and intoxication of wealth**, they perform sacrifices which are so in name only, with ostentation and regardless of the injunctions.

> 16.18 **Depending on their egoism, power and pride, and also of desire and wrath, these malicious men** hate Me in their own bodies and in those of others.

> 16.19 I cast for ever those **hateful, cruel, evil-doers in the worlds, the vilest of human beings,** verily into the demoniacal classes.

Really, its a big list of criteria that an atheist must also satisfy in order to be destined for hell.

Comment: Two question:1)He also must go to everlasting hell, who imputes falsehood to the Vedas, the scriptures, the Brahmanas, the gods, and the ceremonies in honour of the Pitris, is this statement by yudhishthir false, 2) criticising veda doesn't come under anter, greed and lust so how it's path to hell

Comment: 1) On this topic, I have written an answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58221/31356 These slokas on everlasting hell are absent from the critical edition of Mahabharata.

Comment: 2) It is possible to find people who criticize vedas, but dont necessarily have other qualities listed to obtain naraka. Several criticisms of vedas, direct or indirect, are found in other Hindu scriptures as well.

Comment: @Hope Yudhishtir is Dharmaraj, so...

Comment: @Haridasa so vivekanand will go to hell if verses aren't prakshipt

Comment: @Hope depends if he was confused or not sure, then him imputing falsehood may not be considered for Naraka I see this as more purposeful.

Comment: Anyways he did a lot of good, so he may face some time in hell and then heaven as we all do.

Comment: @Haridasa he also was a smoker.

Comment: @Hope I am not god :)